# i want to remove duplicate ```&nbsp;``` if they are consecutive but my condition "if($value === "&nbsp;") " is not working

Tags: php

string :  `&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;373704 &nbsp;02.01.18 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;719,19 &nbsp; &nbsp; 381057 &nbsp;13.01.18 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;0,00`

my function:

```
 public function removeDuplicateNBSP($string){
        $textArray = explode(" ", $string);
        foreach ($textArray as $key => $value) {
            if($value === "&nbsp;" && $textArray[key+1] === "&nbsp;"){
                unset($textArray[$key]);
                array_values($textArray);
                print_r($value);
                echo "</br>";
            }
        } 
        $arrayToText = implode(" ", $textArray);
        return $arrayToText;
    }
```

expected result : `&nbsp;373704 &nbsp;02.01.18 &nbsp;719,19 &nbsp;381057 &nbsp;13.01.18 &nbsp;0,00`

What i want: i want to remove duplicate `&nbsp;` if they are consecutive but my condition is not working. what can i do?

Comment: `$textArray[key+1]` `key` should probably be `$key`

Comment: you probably want to take a look into `php` `regex` (`preg-replace.php`), or just `str_replace`.

Comment: just a thought ... to make your question more generic, would be: *how to remove duplications ( multiple occurrences of a substring)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply filter all the `&nbsp;` values:

```php
$string = '&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;373704 &nbsp;02.01.18 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;719,19 &nbsp; &nbsp; 381057 &nbsp;13.01.18 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;0,00';     

$values = explode(' ', $string);
$func = function($val) {
    return $val !== '&nbsp;';
};

$filtered = implode(' ', array_filter($values, $func));

echo $filtered;
```